# Unresolved External Symbol - How to fix?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm pretty new to programming. I have run into this error that I can't figure out. You should be able to put in a score and it will use the information that is pre put in the array and tell you how many students got that grade.

The error msg I get is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Ch11_27, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 4/4/2013 1:17:26 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Ch11_27.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl checkScore(int * const,int * const)" (?checkScore@@YAXQAH0@Z) referenced in function _main
1>F:\a School Stuff TJC Spring 2013\Intro Prog\C++ Projects\Ch11_27\Debug\Ch11_27.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Here is my code:

```
//Advanced27.cpp - displays the number of students
//earning a specific score
//Created/revised by <your name> on <current date>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void checkScore( int scores[], int storage[]);

int main()
{
    //declare array
    int scores[20] = {90, 54, 23, 75, 67, 89, 99, 100, 34, 99, 
                      97, 76, 73, 72, 56, 73, 72, 20, 86, 99};
    int storage[4] = {0};
    char answer = ' ';

    cout << "Do you want to check a grade? (Y/N): ";
    cin >> answer;
    answer = toupper(answer);

    while (answer = 'Y')
    {
        checkScore(scores, storage);

    cout << "Do you want to check a grade? (Y/N): ";
    cin >> answer;
    answer = toupper(answer);

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}   //end of main function

//*****Function Defenitions*****
void checkGrade(int scores[], int storage[])
{
    int temp = 0;
    int earnedScore = 0;

    cout << "Enter a grade you want to check: ";
    cin >> earnedScore;

    for (int sub = 0; sub <= 20; sub +=1)
    {
        if (scores[sub] = earnedScore)
        {
            storage[temp] += 1;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Look carefully at your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `checkGrade()` below the main()-function should probably be called `void checkScore( int scores[], int storage[])`

Comment: @Blader2themax10: If you like an answer, vote it up or accept it!

Comment: I will once I have 15 rep.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your function definition is named differently to your function declaration:

```
void checkScore( int scores[], int storage[]);
void checkGrade(int scores[], int storage[])
```

You need to pick one or the other. The compiler gets to your call to `checkScore` and sees that there is no definition for it. Changing the definition to be called `checkScore` would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you *declared* the function to be named `checkScore` but you *defined* the function to be named `checkGrade`. Then when `main()` tries calling `checkScore` the compiler says "OK, that was declared above. I'll allow it even though I can't find it. It might be in a different library or source file.". Then it is the responsibility of the linker to find it. Since the linker finds `checkGrade` but doesn't find `checkScore`, the linker then throws the error saying undefined reference (`main()` references `checkScore` and not `checkGrade`).

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have declared your function

```
void checkScore( int scores[], int storage[]);
```

but not actually defined it (giving it a function-body).
Define your function like

```
void checkScore( int scores[], int storage[]){

}
```

to make this error go away.