# Error LNK2019 with creating DirectX11

Tags: c++, c, directx, directx-11, lnk2019

Hi I'm currently trying to set up Direct X project in visual studio 2015.

i have downloaded the correct SDK and linked the project to the correct directories, from what i have been taught at uni. (this entire project was just meant to be a simple copy the code across from a word document provided)

I found that this is the only line of code that results in error.

```
if (FAILED(InitialiseWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow)))
{
    DXTRACE_MSG("Failed to create Window");
    return 0;
}
```

if i comment out the DXTRACE_MSG then the program complies correctly.

The exact error is LNK2019  unresolved external symbol __vsnprintf referenced in function "long __stdcall StringVPrintfWorkerA(char *,unsigned int,unsigned int *,char const *,char *)" (?StringVPrintfWorkerA@@YGJPADIPAIPBD0@Z)   Tutorial 01 Exercise 01 C:\Users\Tony\Desktop\AGP\Tutorial 1 Exercise 01\dxerr.lib(dxerra.obj).

So overall i just need help in understanding the error, why it occurs and what i can do to rectify it so i can continue moving along with what i need for my assignment.

any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <D3D11.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <D3DX11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <DxErr.h>

//int (WINAPIV * __vsprintf)(char*, size_t, const char*, va_list) = __vsprintf;


// Global Variables

HINSTANCE g_hInst = NULL;
HWND g_hWnd = NULL;

// Rename for each tutorial
char g_TutorialName[100] = "Tutorial 01 Exercise 01\0";


// Forward declarations


HRESULT InitialiseWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


// Entry point to the program. Initializes everything and goes into a message processing
// loop. Idle time is used to render the scene.

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR     lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{


    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    if (FAILED(InitialiseWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow)))
    {
        DXTRACE_MSG("Failed to create Window");
        return 0;
    }
    // Main message loop
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {
            //do somthing
        }
    }

     return (int)msg.wParam;

}

// Register class and create window

HRESULT InitialiseWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
     // Give your app window your own name
     char Name[100] = "Hello World\0";

     // Register class
      WNDCLASSEX wcex = { 0 };
     wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    // wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH )( COLOR_WINDOW + 1); // Needed for non-D3D apps

    wcex.lpszClassName = Name;


    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)) return E_FAIL;

    // Create window
    g_hInst = hInstance;
    RECT rc = { 0, 0, 640, 480 };
    AdjustWindowRect(&rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    g_hWnd = CreateWindow(Name, g_TutorialName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rc.right - rc.left,
        rc.bottom - rc.top, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!g_hWnd)
        return E_FAIL;

    ShowWindow(g_hWnd, nCmdShow);
    return S_OK;
}


// Called every time the application receives a message

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     PAINTSTRUCT ps;
     HDC hdc;
    switch (message)
        {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
         if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
             DestroyWindow(g_hWnd);
        return 0;

    default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the library that contains the `vsnprintf` function - I can't tell you which one it is, but that's the problem.

Comment: So many similar:  [Unresolved Error How to fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819095/unresolved-external-symbol-how-to-fix), [How to Solve the error LNK2019](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886397/how-to-solve-the-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-function), and [What is an unresolved symbol and how to fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)